# javafx tabpane's pane content not working and tab not switching

Tags: java, javafx-8

Hi i have made a javafx app with loading New Tabs inside TabPane.Application running great except the New Tabs Button,TextFields are not working and also the switching of in tabpane is not working.

**FXML**

```
<GridPane id="content" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="mainParent" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gvj.sndp.view.controller.HomeController">
  <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.18421052631578946" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <items>
            <TreeView fx:id="menuTreeView" prefHeight="273.0" prefWidth="115.0" />
            <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" rotateGraphic="true" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" onAction="#addMemberSelect" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="37.0" text="AM">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" onAction="#addSelfHelpSelect" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="55.0" text="ASH">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton onAction="#addOfficeBarrierSelect" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="43.0" text="AOB">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox />
  </children>
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="22.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="22.0" prefHeight="22.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <RowConstraints valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
  </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

When the user click the button a new tab is create and loaded to the TabPane.
Why isn't not working.What i'm doing wrong??

**Controller**

```
@FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;
    @FXML
    private void addMemberSelect() {
        App.getInstance().showProgressIndicator(myController);
        Task<FXMLLoader> task = new Task<FXMLLoader>() {
            @Override
            protected FXMLLoader call() throws Exception {
                return new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(Screens.ADD_MEMBER));
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                super.succeeded();
                    Tab tabA = new Tab("Add Member");
                    final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
                    scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
                    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
                    try {
                        scrollPane.setContent(get().load());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tabA.setContent(scrollPane);
                    tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);
                App.getInstance().hideProgressIndicator(myController);
            }

            @Override
            protected void failed() {
                super.failed();
                App.getInstance().hideProgressIndicator(myController);
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();

    }
```

Comment: Please share your `com.gvj.sndp.view.controller.HomeController` controller class.

Comment: @kornisb code updated.